# How to divide 2 values in a column by condition

Tags: sql, select, divide

I have a table like this

```
metrics                  metrics_value 

pageviews                111
bounces                  222
avgSessionsDuration      100
```

I need to calculate new values, ideally without adding a new column

1. avgSessionsDuration / 60 AS minutes
2. (bounces/pageviews)*100 AS bounce rate

My desired output

```
metrics                  metrics_value 

pageviews                111
bounces                  222
avgSessionsDuration      100

bounce rate              200
minutes                  1,6
```

With getting minutes it is ok, but with the second new metric I can't get how to do it

What I ve done

```
#  Get minutes

SELECT metrics, metrics_value,
CASE WHEN metrics = 'avgSessionDuration' THEN metrics_value / 60
END
FROM Table

#  Get bounces and pageviews
SELECT bounces / pageviews, 
      (SELECT metrics
      WHERE metrics = 'bounces'
      ) bounces,

      (SELECT metrics
      WHERE dmetrics = 'pageviews'
      ) pageviews

FROM Table Table
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just want `union all` and separate calculations for each new metric::

```
SELECT metrics, metrics_value
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT 'minutes', metrics_value / 60
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bounce rate',
       (100* MAX(CASE WHEN metrics = 'bounces' THEN metrics_value END) /
        MAX(CASE WHEN metrics = 'pageviews' THEN metrics_value END)
       )
FROM t;
```

Comment: Hello, with minutes it worked super, but with bounces it returns NULL((

Comment: @AnnaDmitrieva . . . Check the spelling of the two metrics names.

Comment: @AnnaDmitrieva is there a reason that you accepted a wrong answer? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=460066b471ef2198e3107e932a64e940

Answer (score 1):

Use subqueries for each of the values that you want:

```
select metrics, metrics_value  from tablename
union all
select 'bounce rate', 
  100.0 * (select metrics_value from tablename where metrics = 'bounces') /
  (select metrics_value from tablename where metrics = 'pageviews') 
union all
select 'minutes',
  (select metrics_value from tablename where metrics = 'avgSessionsDuration') / 60.0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=65409fac44bd3c24708c72e4f3a54b88).
Results:

```
> metrics             | metrics_value   
> :------------------ | :---------------
> pageviews           | 111
> bounces             | 222
> avgSessionsDuration | 100
> bounce rate         | 200
> minutes             | 1.6
```

Note that depending on the database that you use you may need to add a `FROM` clause to the last 2 `UNION`ed queries like:

```
FROM dual
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, it returns All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: In the 1st query I changed * to `metrics, metrics_value`. Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT 
bounces.metrics / pageviews.metrics AS bounceRate
FROM  (SELECT metrics
        WHERE metrics = 'bounces'
      ) bounces,
       (SELECT metrics
         WHERE metrics = 'pageviews'
      ) pageviews
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an elegant way, but you may do that step by step like this:

```
WITH
-- Let's create table same, to shown in your example: 
  metrics_table AS(
  SELECT
    'page_views' AS metrics,
    111 AS metrics_value
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'bounces',
    222
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'avgSessionsDuration',
    100)

--  get everything from it: 
SELECT
  metrics,
  metrics_value
FROM
  metrics_table

-- unite it with calculation for seconds transformed to minutes
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'minutes',
  metrics_value/60
FROM
  metrics_table
WHERE
  metrics = 'avgSessionsDuration'

-- and finnaly add bounce rate:
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'bounce rate',
  bounces/page_views * 100
FROM (
    -- trick called inline view used here
    SELECT
        metrics_value AS bounces
    FROM
        metrics_table
    WHERE
        metrics = 'bounces') -- bounce
JOIN (
    SELECT
        metrics_value AS page_views
    FROM
         metrics_table
    WHERE
         metrics = 'page_views') -- page views

--we just want to join it in any condition:
ON
  TRUE
```

If any clarifications or further help needed - fill free to ask it.